# Problem with npm install: illegal operation on a directory

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm trying to upgrade npm:

```
npm install -g npm
```

But I keep getting a similar warning hundreds of times:

```
warn tar EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, open '/tmp/npm-4154-cadf3470/unpack-87786b4c/bin/node-gyp-bin'
```

My stacktrace ends with a error which indicates a file can't be found:

```
npm ERR! path /private/tmp/npm-4154-cadf3470/unpack-87786b4c/node_modules/run-queue/package.json
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/private/tmp/npm-4154-cadf3470/unpack-87786b4c/node_modules/run-queue/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
```

Is anyone else having a similar problem?

Comment: Idk if this would help, but have you seen if `sudo npm install -g npm` results in a different output?

Comment: @therobinkim I get the same result unfortunately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had to [uninstall node completely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177954/how-do-i-completely-uninstall-node-js-and-reinstall-from-beginning-mac-os-x) and reinstall using brew:

```
brew install node
```

Comment: Good solution! For what it's worth, I've found I had fewer issues w/ `npm` when I've used `nvm` to install `node`. https://github.com/creationix/nvm